# Getting Uncaught SoapFault exception: [2] Access denied Magento

Tags: magento, exception, soap, access-denied

Hi is it possible to use soap from localhost to live server.
I have create soap user on live site and i am trying to use it from my localhost

http://lab.example.com/turn-key-mart/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('111111', '111111');

but when i run the file it gives me the Uncaught SoapFault exception: [2] Access denied.Is it possible to connect localhost to live server.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code and working well

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('testuser', 'test123');
```

where `testuser` is username and `test123` is apikey.